# Server stuck at reboot: A stop job is running for Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc using dmeventd or progress polling

Tags: ubuntu

I rebooted a Ubuntu 20.04 server.

It did not come back up.

On the screen it said:

```
A stop job is running for Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc using dmeventd or progress polling (9min 56s/11min)
```

Waiting until 11min did not help: It simply increased the value to 12min 31s.

To me this is unacceptable: When I say 'reboot' I really want the machine to reboot - even if it means killing jobs that cause data loss. This is because the alternative here was simply to power cycle the machine.

How can I say: Do not increase the timeout? If you are stuck for at most 3 minutes, proceed.

Comment: I mean, there's `systemctl reboot --force`, but you **really** want to read the manpage before doing that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Normally the server reboots fine, but apparently this time something got stuck. So what I really want is to trigger `systemctl reboot --force` if a shutdown task takes longer than 3 minutes, because the alternative in this case is for me to power cycle it.